# jssor How to Increase Number of Images

Tags: javascript, jssor

I cannot add more than 6 images in the slider. How can I increase the number of images that are displayed?  When I increase images to 7, the seventh one does not work into the rotation.

Here is the code I am using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
//Define an array of slideshow transition code
var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        {$Duration:1800,$Delay:30,$Cols:10,$Rows:5,$Clip:15,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$FlyDirection:5,$Reverse:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs,$Assembly:2050,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad},$ScaleHorizontal:1,$ScaleVertical:0.2,$Outside:true,$Round:{$Top:1.3}},
        {$Duration:600,$Delay:30,$Cols:8,$Rows:4,$SlideOut:true,$FlyDirection:6,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuart,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuart,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear},$Opacity:2},
        {$Duration:1800,$Delay:30,$Cols:10,$Rows:5,$Clip:15,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$SlideOut:true,$FlyDirection:5,$Reverse:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs,$Assembly:2050,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad},$ScaleHorizontal:1,$ScaleVertical:0.2,$Outside:true,$Round:{$Top:1.3}},
        {$Duration:1500,$Delay:20,$Cols:8,$Rows:4,$Clip:15,$During:{$Left:[0.1,0.9],$Top:[0.1,0.9]},$SlideOut:true,$FlyDirection:9,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationZigZag,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad},$ScaleHorizontal:0.3,$ScaleVertical:0.3,$Outside:true,$Round:{$Left:0.8,$Top:2.5}},
        {$Duration:1200,$Cols:6,$Rows:6,$Clip:15,$During:{$Left:[0.2,0.8],$Top:[0.2,0.8],$Clip:[0,0.2]},$FlyDirection:10,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$ChessMode:{$Column:15,$Row:15},$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseSwing},$ScaleClip:0.5},
        {$Duration:1200,$SlideOut:true,$FlyDirection:1,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear},$ScaleHorizontal:0.3,$Opacity:2,$Outside:true},
];
var options = {
    $AutoPlay: true,
    $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1,
            $ShowLink: true
        }
};


var slides = '<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 728px; height: 90px;">';
        slides +=    '<DIV><a href="http://www.tradingstreet.co/ninja.html" target="_new"><IMG src="/banner_ads-hd/ninja_logo.png"></a></DIV>';
    slides +=    '<DIV><a href="http://www.mbtrading.com" target="_new"><IMG src="/banner_ads-hd/mb_trading_logo.png"></a></DIV>';
    slides +=    '<DIV><a href="http://www.tradingstreet.co/kinetick.html" target="_new"><IMG src="/banner_ads-hd/kinetick_logo.png"></a></DIV>';
    slides +=    '<DIV><a href="http://www.tradingstreet.co/ninja_brokerage.html" target="_new"><IMG src="/banner_ads-hd/ninja_brokerage.png"></a></DIV>';
    slides +=    '<DIV><a href="http://www.traderkingdom.com" target="_new"><IMG src="/banner_ads-hd/tk_360x50.jpg"></a></DIV>';
    slides +=    '<DIV><a href="http://wallstreet2easystreet.blogspot.com" target="_new"><IMG src="/banner_ads-hd/ws2es_banner.png"></a></DIV></div>';
    slides +=    '<DIV><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheGoldReport-StreetwiseExclusiveFullArticles" target="_new"><IMG src="/banner_ads-hd/tgr_masthead_728x90.jpg"></a></DIV></div>';
//console.log("setting slides 2");
$("#slider2").html(slides);
$("#slider2").css({"position": "relative", "top": "0px", "left": "0px", "width": "728px", "height": "90px"});
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider2', options);

});
```

Comment: Not sure with jssor, but I see 7 slides and 6 transitions, maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra '<DIV>', it makes your last image outside of 'slides' container.

Please replace

```
slides +=    '<DIV><a href="http://wallstreet2easystreet.blogspot.com" target="_new"><IMG src="/banner_ads-hd/ws2es_banner.png"></a></DIV></div>';
```

with

```
slides +=    '<DIV><a href="http://wallstreet2easystreet.blogspot.com" target="_new"><IMG src="/banner_ads-hd/ws2es_banner.png"></a></DIV>';
```

Also, if you want jssor slider fill your image in the 'slides' container, please replace all

```
<a href=
```

with

```
<a u="iamge" href=
```